# Input a shapefile to Rshiny and read the data from it

Tags: r, shiny, shapefile

I am trying to make a shiny dashboard where the user can input a shapefile and extract the data in it. The code seems returning error 'cannot open data source'. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "Choose shp File", accept = ".shp")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("contents")
      )
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$contents <- renderTable({
      library(dplyr)
      library(rgdal)
      file <- input$file1
      req(file)
      x=readOGR(file$datapath) %>% .@data
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A single `.shp` file is not enough for the shiny app to work with. YOu can consider a solution posted on Rcommunity by user fiorepalombina.

You can find the answer [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shinyfiles-and-shapefiles/89099/4).